# why is -y needed with DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

Tags: ubuntu, debian, apt

I understood that to use apt-get without user's interaction, it is needed to set the variable DEBIAN_FRONTEND to noninteractive.

But looking on the net, I saw that people set DEBIAN_FRONTEND to noninteractive and still use the -y option. But why if noninteractive removes all user's interactions ?

An other point, to remove all interactions, I saw that I have to set APT_LISTCHANGES_FRONTEND to none. I did not understand clearly the effect of this variable. Does it control what is displayed or does it remove some user's interactions ?

Thanks for any help.

Best regards